# Can't start mysql after installing mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ubuntu-18.04

I have just installed mariadb but when I do `sudo mysql` the I get this error:
`ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'auth_socket' is not loaded`.
i have looked online for fixes but I cannot find any that actually work.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing during installation you did not provide a password so it is trying to use unix sockets. If you want to use a password for root then first start mysql without the grant table

`mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

Then ALTER user root and provide a password (follow the mysql doc for this). Then restart.